# Error setting column name R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to rename a column in R. I have a list and want to rename one column of a dataframe within that list.

Here's an excerpt from my Console.

```
> colnames(Prem[["TasNSW"]])
 [1] "Master Client Number" "Master Client Name"   "Policy Number"        "State"               
 [5] "Policy Name"          "Year"                 "Effective Date"       "Expiry Date"         
 [9] "Estimate/Actual"      "Total Wages"          "Master Client Name  "
> colnames(Prem[["TasNSW"]][10]) <- "Remuneration"
> colnames(Prem[["TasNSW"]])
 [1] "Master Client Number" "Master Client Name"   "Policy Number"        "State"               
 [5] "Policy Name"          "Year"                 "Effective Date"       "Expiry Date"         
 [9] "Estimate/Actual"      "Total Wages"          "Master Client Name  "
```

What I'd expect to see is

```
> colnames(Prem[["NSW"]])
 [1] "Master Client Number" "Master Client Name"   "Policy Number"        "State"               
 [5] "Policy Name"          "Year"                 "Effective Date"       "Expiry Date"         
 [9] "Estimate/Actual"      "Total Wages"          "Master Client Name  "
> colnames(Prem[["NSW"]][10]) <- "Remuneration"
> colnames(Prem[["NSW"]])
 [1] "Master Client Number" "Master Client Name"   "Policy Number"        "State"               
 [5] "Policy Name"          "Year"                 "Effective Date"       "Expiry Date"         
 [9] "Estimate/Actual"      "Remuneration"         "Master Client Name  "
```

I've used that code a number of times so I think the issue is based on its presence in a list. What have I missed?

Comment: You need to move the `)` - `colnames(Prem[["TasNSW"]])[10] <- "Remuneration"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misplaced the closing parentheses here:

```
colnames(Prem[["TasNSW"]][10]) <- "Remuneration"
```

Instead, try this:

```
colnames(Prem[["TasNSW"]])[10] <- "Remuneration"
```

And you'll get the expected result